# Vertically aligning a menu with table display

Tags: html, css

After hours of Googling I managed to make the `{ display : table }` and `{ vertical-align : bottom }` work. However, if I change the name of my `div` class called "big div" to any other name, then the table properties on the container and UL items below stop working and the menu is no longer positioned.

```
.big div
{
    background-color : #328332 ;
    width : 100% ;
    height : 90px ;
    margin-top : 0 ;
    color : white ;
    text-align : center ;
    position : relative 
}

.tablecontain
{
  display : table
}

.menu 
{
    margin : 0  ;
    list-style : none ;
    padding : 0 ;
    display : table-cell ;
    vertical-align : bottom
}

.menu li 
{
    display : inline-block
}

.menu li a
{
    text-decoration : none ;
    padding : 15px ;
    background-color : #006400 ;
    color : white ;
    display : block ;
    margin : 0 
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/43fgsnsk) is a JSfiddle where it works properly.

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/43fgsnsk/1/) is one where I have given the div another name of "container" and it stops working.

I have tried applying the `display: table`, and `table-cell` property to different elements but I have not been able to do it any other way. I should also mention I tried applying the table property to the "big div" class without using the `tablecontain` `div` at all. That didn't work.

Also, I am curious about other ways of doing this. I can do the position relative on the container and position absolute on the menu, but are there other or more commonly used ways of moving menus around?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `div`  is a reserved word in css to select **any** `div` **tag**

Your class is named `.big`  **not** `big div`

you can add style to an element using multiple classes by **spacing** every class so in this case:

```
.big div
```

you're selecting the class `.big` that contains a `div`

Answer (score 1):

`.big div` selects the `div` element under the `.big` class. If you want to change the name of the `.big div` to `.container` and applying style to `.container` it is not working because you have to apply the style to `tablecontain` to work. In your second fiddle replace the `.container` to `tablecontain`.

Comment: OK, I can't believe I have made a simple error and spent so long on it. But effectively I did not need the wrapper / div container named tablecontain at all. All I needed to do was apply the display : table property to the parent div of the ul?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
.container
{
   background-color : #328332 ;
   width : 100% ;
   height : 90px ;
   margin-top : 0 ;
  color : white ;
  text-align : center ;
  position : relative 
}
```

To

```
.container div
 {
   background-color : #328332 ;
   width : 100% ;
   height : 90px ;
   margin-top : 0 ;
   color : white ;
   text-align : center ;
  position : relative 
 }
```

It works fine, hope it helps